# Validate with Json

Tags: javascript, json, post, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

-- Controller --

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Check(string Name)
{
   var deptFound = new Department();

   using (var db = new ShopModelContainer())
   {
       deptFound = db.Departments.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name.Trim().Equals(Name.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
   }

   return deptFound != null;
}
```

-- View --

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

JS File:

```
$('#Name').change(function () {
    var exists;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'Check?Name=' + $('#Name').val(),
        data: "{'Name': '" + arguments.Value + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            exists = result.d;
        }
    });
    arguments.isValid != exists;
});
```

well, I want to check on the client side if there is already a record in departments with the name entered in the field. What should I change to make it work? Btw the url is right. I tested in I.E. debugger and it's passing the controller name automatically, so I just need put the method name.

Comment: Where do you get `arguments.Value` from? The `arguments` variables does not have a `Value` member, to my knowledge.

Comment: It was a just example that I watch in tutorial, I'm asking how can I make this validation based on this scope, understand?